# Flutter - Listview poor performance with large list when scroll to specific item

Tags: flutter, performance, listview, freeze, scrollto

I had one problem with listview, i need create a listview with a large list, but sometimes i need to scroll to a specific list and when its happens, the app freeze for some time and before scroll to the item, i know that it is because when you scroll to a listview.builder while use scroll this witdget will building all itens while scrolling.

I did it as solution, let's say, custom way to do this without third party packages is create a take skip. You could implement this logic on backend in query, or in widgets like this.

https://github.com/UriDevzera/lazyloadinglistview

Of course man, it is a very simple example, and i think that should be improved. Example, the loader could be a progress line indicator on top list, or an items inside the listview, having a better approach.

Please, let me know what you guys think about this one.

Comment: Please show us some code snippets, how you have implemented the list and how your scrolling is implemented.